# Stumped on how to return reversed cstring

Tags: c++, c-strings

First and foremost, I'm new to cstrings and I have to use them for the assignment. I wish I didn't have to since they're a pain.

Anyway, the issue I'm having is with a function that accepts password, reverses the order, and passes it back to main. For whatever reason, I can't get it to populate the cstring tasked with holding the password. I've tried more than one way to get it working, but I've had no luck.

The function:

```
char* Reverse_Pass(char p_word[])
{
    int last_let = strlen(p_word);
    int rev_index = 0;

    char* rev_pass = new char[last_let];

    //cout << "\ntest 3";

    rev_pass[0] = '\0';
    //for (int i = last_let; i >= 0; i--)

    while (p_word[last_let] != '\0')
    {
        rev_pass[rev_index] = p_word[last_let];
        rev_index++;
        last_let--;
    }
    return rev_pass;
}
```

I tried using a for loop for the process, but it throws a break point message when the result was sent to another function for verification of said password. This function at least allows the program to run without error. The issue I'm having is logical, but I can't see it.

Comment: `char* rev_pass = new char[last_let];` You need to allocate space for the '\0' Also make sure you are putting it at the end of `rev_pass` before you return.

Comment: Just use `std::string` and `std::reverse()`. Dump c-style strings.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here.  First off is that `strlen` returns the length of the string not counting the null terminator.  That means when you do

```
while (p_word[last_let] != '\0')
```

`p_word[last_let]` is `'\0'` since `cstrign[strlen(cstring)]` is the null terminator and the loop never executes.  All of this though is still wrong.  Really what you want to do is stop when `last_let` is less than `0`.

This also affects `rev_pass`.  You use

```
char* rev_pass = new char[last_let];
```

Which gives you enough storage for the string but not enough for the null terminator that all cstrings must have.  What you need is

```
char* rev_pass = new char[last_let + 1];
```

Lastly, you never null terminate `rev_pass`.  Since you know that it will be the last position that needs the null terminator you can simply use

```
rev_pass[last_let] = '\0';
```

After you allocate it.

All of those changes gives you

```
char* Reverse_Pass(char p_word[])
{
    int last_let = strlen(p_word);
    int rev_index = 0;

    char* rev_pass = new char[last_let + 1];
    rev_pass[last_let] = '\0';

    while (last_let > 0)
    {
        rev_pass[rev_index++] = p_word[--last_let];
    }
    return rev_pass;
}
```

Comment: I'd say that the check on p_word[rev_index] it's a little bit tricky as you are testing a value that you are not using in the loop (pword uses last_let as index), what about  
    
   while (p_word[rev_index] != '\0')
    {
        rev_pass[--last_let] = p_word[rev_index++];
    }

Comment: @StefanoBuora It is "tricky" but I do not see a way it can fail.  I suppose `while (last_let > 0)` would also work

Comment: it works, no doubt. I think "while (last_let >0)" either can help to keep the code more consistent.

Comment: @StefanoBuora Changed it.

Comment: Instead of the hand-written loop you could also use [`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy).

Answer (score 0):

I would say three things here:

1. `new char[last_let];` should be `new char[last_let+1];`, space for /0 not included in `strlen` returned value
2. `rev_pass[0] = '\0';` should be `rev_pass[last_let] = '\0'; you want the string to be 0 *terminated*
3. the end loop condition is `p_word[last_let] != '\0`, but you are decreasing the value of last_let...so you are checking for a 0 byte *before* the begin of the string that is not guarantee in anyway. the strings are 0 terminated!

For the (3) I think if you flip the index usage in the loop (eg last_let for the reversed string and rev_index for the source should make the trick)

Happy coding, Ste